# Alert based on the field value in Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, elastic-cloud

I want to send alert from Kibana whenever someone adds the document which meets the conditions. I am using Elastic Cloud Kibana version 8.5.2

Below are my rule configurations

[image]

[image]

I am indexing the document from the Dev Tools api, query is working but it doesn't send alert when I index new document, does anyone knows what is going wrong in my configuration.

```
filter_roll = filter rolledbooksfile where column withe current kde name is equal to 'Y'
            filter_roll1 = filter_roll with filter which return only ['book'] column
            filter_roll2 = filter_roll with filter which return only ['bookid'] column
            filter_roll2 = rename columns to ['book']
            filter_roll3 = concatenation of filter_roll1 and filter_roll2, reset the index and drop duplicates.
            filter_roll4 = inner merge of filter_roll3 with entity_eligibleallbooks on 'book'  [filter_roll3] is calculated at toterredtrades step.
            filter_roll_li = convert the filter_roll4['book'] to list.
            filter_roll_lii = join the element of the above list with '|'
            if filter_roll_lii is not ""(empty):
                merged_df = totnumcr01tradestable with filter where ['book'] contains 'filter_roll_lii' and reset the index.
            else:
                merged_df = create the empty with the columns same as totnumcr01tradestable
            
            if filter_roll_lii is not ""(empty):
                merged_df = totnumcr01tradestable with filter where ['book'] contains 'filter_roll_lii' and reset the index.
            else:
                merged_df = create the empty with the columns same as totnumcr01tradestable
            toterredtrades = float value of total number of rows in merged_df['totalgbp'] column
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to kibana alerts also, but I think you have to make sure about your email-connector configuration and correct performance.
have you tested it first?
If it works properly, check the other options next.
We used  an index connector to make sure it matches correctly.
Another thing that you can check is Alert History. Hope you find it soon.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).